# exponential distribution for a traffic light

Tags: probability, random-variables, exponential-distribution

I'm new to this topic and I'm sorry if my question in basic.

Imagine a traffic light that starts working from 7 a.m. every morning, with the frequency of 1 minute green light and 3 minutes red light (it starts with green). Let the time you reach the traffic light be a random variable (if needed, $\lambda = \ln(2)$ ). If $Y$ is the time you wait at the traffic light, find the cumulative mass function for $Y$.
also, the time you wait and the time you reach the traffic light is all in minutes.

what I have tried so far: exponential random should be used. the time we reach the traffic light then will be:
$$F = 1 - e^{-\lambda*y} = 1 - 2^{-y}$$
but I'm not sure how to include the green or red light factor within the solution.

Comment: I'm guessing that you tried exponential because that's often used for wait times. But exponential is only appropriate for "memoryless" situations, meaning that the probably of changing in the next second is constant.  However if you've waited 2 minutes  59 seconds, then there's a 100 percent chance of changing in the next second.  So this situation doesn't call for an exponential distribution.  In fact, the exponential gives a positive probability of waiting more than 3 minutes.

Comment: actually i saw that question before but it didn't really help me with this one @Kurt G

Comment: I asked my teacher and they confirmed the right method starts with using exponential distribution, but I don't know how to solve it to the end. @T.J.Gaffney

Comment: Hint: Let $[0,\infty)$ be partitioned by intervals $G_i,R_i$ of length one minute, resp., three minutes. Find out the absolute times when these intervals start and end. Since we know that your arrival time $T$ at the traffic light is exponential we know the probability that it falls into any of these intervals. The waiting time is zero when we fall into a $G_i\,.$ What is it when we fall into a $R_i\,?$ Since we know the probability that this happens we will know the entire distribution of the waiting time.